# vba to format/parse dataset in csv

Tags: vba, vbscript

Can anyone see whats wrong with this script?

```
Option Explicit
Dim lrow As Long
Dim lcol As Long
Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long
Dim strow As Long
Dim fso As Object
Dim xl As Excel.Application
Dim wb As Object
Dim ws As Object
Dim f As Object
Dim Val As Object

Sub arrange_data()

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Set xl = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set wb = xl.Workbooks.Add
Set ws = wb.Sheets(1)

Set f = fso.OpenTextfile("<path to destination>\gg3-xtra.csv")

i = 1
j = 1

Do Until f.AtEndOfStream
Val = f.ReadLine
  If Val = "" Then
    i = 1
    j = j + 1
  Else
    ws.Cells(i, j).Value = Val
    i = i + 1
  End If
Loop

f.Close
wb.SaveAs "output.xls"
End Sub
```

I would like this script to perform the following action

What the dataset looks like now

Dataset1

…

…

Dataset2

..

..

Dataset3

What the script should make it look like

```
Dataset1           Dataset2           Dataset3

...                     …                     …

…                     …                     …

…                     …                     …
```

Answer (score 0):

From what you're showing it seems like `Val` will never equal `""` if your csv file has no empty lines.  Does your csv file have any blank rows between Datasets?